# This payment method has been declined. (Credit card, debit, PayPal and Redeem)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

[Image example of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXOoP.png)

Can access to the product but i can't pay with any method. This payment method has been declined. (Credit card, debit, PayPal and Redeem) neither of these works. I do not know where to modify or if i have to add some special settings in my console of the App. Please Help!

My code:
public void inAppBilling (){

```
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
    skuList.add(idReal);
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
    Bundle skuDetails;
    try{
        //Toast.makeText(PurchaseActivity.this, "Ya has entrado chaval", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  (“inapp” or "subs").
        skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,getPackageName(),"inapp",querySkus);

        int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {
            ArrayList<String> responseList
                    = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

            for (String thisResponse : responseList) {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                String sku = object.getString("productId");
                String price = object.getString("price");
                System.out.println("price "+price+"  Sku" +sku+"  "+currentUser.getBoolean("completeContent"));
                if (sku.equals(idReal)){
                    System.out.println("price "+price+"  Sku" +sku+"  "+currentUser.getBoolean("completeContent"));
                    //Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");

                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp",null);

                    //"+U7F9DbU//IE+Xl1kOuMM2xkTIpL58FjWAoyh5WriyC8jqoQYMOvMrpwIDAQAB");

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                            new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to all see this Question, it was a problem of Google developer account, it seems it was too old 7 or 8 years, so in-app purchases or Payment stuff wasn't supported. Cheers!